Best textbooks/resources for "advanced" probability theory?
When I say "Advanced Probability", I mean for a person acquainted with the measure-theoretic foundations of probability theory, that wants to learn about Stochastic Processes from there, in discrete and continuous time (including martingales in discrete and continuous time, martingale convergence theorems, brownian motion). I have a set of lecture notes I am reading but would appreciate some alternative perspectives on the theory. Any textbooks or resources on SDEs would also be very welcome!
I appreciate this isn't very advanced theory for some of you, but trying to find an "Advanced" probability textbook is something I have found difficult since its very vague.
EDIT: Since this is very broad, I am interested in any textbooks at the early graduate level, with a bend towards applications. Since I am unfamiliar with the field I am unsure on how to pin this down further. As for the opinion based nature of the question, I completely acknowledge this and welcome opinions!
Thanks!

This is very broad. There are tons of books on stochastic processes, and which is "best" is very opinion based.

Thank you for replying! I edited it, I am looking for any stochastic process books at the early graduate level, with a bend towards applicatons. Since I am unfamiliar with the field I am unsure on how to pin this down further. As for the opinion based nature of the question, I completely acknowledge this and welcome opinions :)

Kallenberg's classic is pretty solid, efficient, and exhaustive. You won't find all the ins and outs of each construction, but no textbook explains everything, you'll sometimes have to find out online the best intuition on something. Thankfully there are plenty of lectures giving contrasting approaches to each topic, which usually allow one to frame a given concept enough to grasp it.

My favourite introduction to stochastic processes and stochastic calculus is the book Stochastic Calculus by Paolo Baldi. It is very clear yet precise at the same time, and comes with hundreds of exercises with full solutions prepared. It hits all the important topics - conditional probability, Markov processes, martingale theory, stochastic calculus with respect to Brownian motion, and SDEs.
If you want to go further after that, the book Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus by Karatzas and Shreve is a nice second read.
These two books should already take you quite far as far as general knowledge goes, but do let me know if you want references for more specific topics!
Edit: I should say that stochastic analysis is not the only type of “advanced” probability. There are far more topics, however it cannot hurt to have a basic background in stochastic analysis.

thank you very much!

@Gabriel Venter You’re most welcome :D
